# Does less sleep lead to weight loss?

Tags: side-effects, weight-loss, sleep-cycles, body-weight

Sleeping less at night time leads to sleep at morning. Does this less sleep lead to weight loss ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually lack of sleep leads to weight gain and not weight loss.

Losing out on sleep creates a viscous cycle in your body, making you more prone to various factors contributing to weight gain. “The more sleep-deprived you are, the higher your levels of the stress hormone cortisol, which increases your appetite,”.

When you’re stressed, your body tries to produce serotonin to calm you down. The easiest way to do that is by eating high-fat, high-carb foods that produce a neurochemical reaction,”says Breus

http://dailyburn.com/life/lifestyle/sleep-deprivation-effects-weight-loss/